# How to see commits on master?

Tags: git

I want to see the last five commits on my master branch. I do:

```
git checkout master 
git log -p -5
```

I see commits that I am pretty sure are not on master.
Because one has a message:

```
 Merge branch 'feature/ABLE-1370' into develop
```

Anything obvious I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try a visual tool. gitg, gitk for example. Otherwise this merge can be normal. In git the branch heads are pointers in the history, and in this way commits can exists simultaneously in more branches. In your case if the related commit's successor was merged to master than this can be normal.

Answer (score 4):

Those commands are correct for viewing the `git log` on your master branch.

With the 'bad' or 'weird' commit: if you merged something else into `develop` and then merged that into `master`, it'll still keep that commit message.

To confirm, you can run `git branch`. The branch that you are on will be the one with a `*` next to it.

Comment: Git checkout might fail with an error message, e.g. if it would overwrite modified files. Git branch should show you the current branch and git log master allows you to view commit logs without changing the branch.

Comment: That's true; it is indeed safer to do that instead of `git checkout`. I've amended it with `git branch`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue you are running into here is the real meaning of "on a branch".

When doing straightforward, linear development history, it's clear which branch each commit is on.  It's on only one (or, technically, *at most* one) branch:

```
$ git checkout branchA
... hack away for a while ...
$ git commit -a -m "new stuff for A" # new commit is on branchA
$ git checkout branchB
... hack some more ...
$ git commit -a -m "new stuff for B"
```

But what happens when you start merging different branches?  After you've made one commit on each of branchA and branchB above, you might have something like this:

```
...-C3--C6       <-- branchA

...-C4--C5--C7   <-- branchB
```

where each `Cn` represents a commit.  The name `branchA` points to commit `C6`, which is the one you made with "new stuff for A", and the name `branchB` points to commit `C7`, which is the one you made with "new stuff for B".  (`C3` and `C4` already existed when you started.  `C6` points back to `C3` as its parent, which is how we can follow the history of `branchA` backwards; and `C7` points to `C5`, which in turn points to `C4`, and so on.)

Now suppose you go back to `branchA` and `git merge branchB`.  This makes a "merge commit"—we could call it commit `C8`, but let's call it `M` for merge:

```
$ git checkout branchA
$ git merge branchB
```

This changes the "commit graph", and now we have this:

```
...-C3--C6-----M <-- branchA
              /
...-C4--C5--C7   <-- branchB
```

The new merge commit, `M`, has *two* parents, commits `C6` and `C7`.  The label `branchA` is changed to point to commit `M`.

If we follow `M` backwards, to see which commits are "on the branch", we will—well, git will, so we should too :-)—follow *both* parents.  Commit `C7` is now "on the branch", as are commits `C5` and `C4` and any previous history that comes before `C4`.

You might wonder, then, how you can tell which commits were "originally" on the branch, before a merge brought in "a bunch of previously-unrelated, but now in the family by marriage" commits.

The fully general answer is "you can't".  This is because the labels—the branch names like `branchB`—are not permanent.  At the moment, it's clear that commits `C7` and its history were just now married in, but if we delete the `branchB` label:

```
$ git branch -d branchB
```

then we are left with only this picture:

```
...-C3--C6-----M <-- branchA
              /
...-C4--C5--C7
```

Sometimes following only the "first parent" of a merge gives a "reasonably accurate" picture of the "main line", as it were, and git has the `--first-parent` flag to follow only the first parent of each merge.

---

This kind of thing "occurs naturally" when two different developers clone a project from some shared repository, and both make (different) changes to some branch and then they decide to merge their changes.  Suppose Carl has a repo with four commits:

```
A--B--C--D        <-- master
```

Alice makes a copy and adds commit `E`:

```
A--B--C--D--E     <-- master
```

Bob makes a copy of Carl's original and adds commit `F`:

```
A--B--C--D--F     <-- master
```

Alice and Bob both tell Carl about their great new features or bug fixes, and Carl decides he wants both.  He can use `git fetch` (along with `git remote add` and such) to bring them in:

```
           E      <-- remotes/alice/master
          /
A--B--C--D        <-- master
          \
           F      <-- remotes/bob/master
```

Now Carl can incorporate both of these into his (Carl's) repo with an easy two step process.  Step one, do a fast forward merge to pick up something (let's say Alice's change):

```
$ git merge alice/master
Updating b6636ec..a430f6d
Fast-forward
[snip]
```

This gives (I'll leave the `remotes/` out of the names now):

```
           E      <-- master, alice/master
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           F      <-- bob/master
```

Next:

```
$ git merge bob/master
```

This has to make a real merge commit (so it does, `merge made by recursive` and all that), giving:

```
           E      <-- alice/master
          / \
A--B--C--D   M    <-- master
          \ /
           F      <-- bob/master
```

If Alice and Bob now fetch the newest updates from Carl, they already have their own local branch names (Alice was calling `E` the tip of `master`) and they don't get each other's names (Alice doesn't "see" Bob here, only Carl "sees" Bob), so Alice adds commit `F` with no label, and `M` with the label `origin/master` (or maybe, if she's picky about names, she'll rename the remote to `carl` so that this is `carl/master`).  She can then move her own `master` to point to `M`:

```
A--B--C--D-E-M    <-- master, origin/master
          \ /
           F
```

Bob likewise can bring in the new commits—for him, they are `E` and `M` instead of `F` and `M` (but M's "first parent" is still `E`):

```
A--B--C--D-E-M    <-- origin/master
          \ /
           F      <-- master [before Bob does the merge]
```

If Bob chooses to slide his `master` label forward (as a fast-forward merge), he now sees exactly the same picture as Alice..

So, for commits E and F, which branch are they on?  They are just "on master", they were even *made* "on master", but Carl did not make them "on master", and Alice and Bob each only made one "on master".  In the end, the only thing git gives you is the final commit graph.

---

To view the commit graph, you can use `gitk` as suggested in comments, or:

```
git log --graph
```

I find this particularly useful when given with `--decorate --oneline`.  Add `--all` to view all branches, and/or `-number` or `-n number` (as in `-5` or `-n 5`) to limit the number of commits seen.